# Obtaining elevation data for points using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation

I am new to QGIS.

I have points uploaded to QGIS that were collected from a GPS, and I need to get elevations for each point (I don't trust the elevation estimations of my GPS).

What is the best way to do this?

Additionally, I realize I'll likely need an elevation raster, and I'm wondering if the Google terrain hybrid or Google satellite hybrid will work or if there's a better option?

Comment: Where in the world?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basic steps to get elevation data in GPS points:

1. Obtain an elevation raster for your area of interest. You'll need a DEM (Digital Elevation Model) raster, which is a raster of pure elevation data without any labels or additional features. (Google terrain is not an elevation raster, it's a combination of a "hillshade" or "[shaded relief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrain_cartography#Shaded_relief)" raster with additional map features like roads, towns, labels, etc.)

   - You can download a DEM from various sources. In the US you can get one from the [National Map Viewer](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/). For Europe (and possibly other parts of the world) try opendem.info.
   - Or you can try to connect to a DEM through a web service, which will save you from having to download and store the data locally. Connecting to a web service in QGIS can be rather tricky, because sometimes the connection just fails and the error message doesn't really explain how to fix it. Here are a few sources where you may be able to connect to an online DEM:

     - https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/543e6b86e4b0fd76af69cf4c
     - https://openmaptiles.com/dem/
     - https://www.usgs.gov/news/new-elevation-map-service-available-usgs-3d-elevation-program
   - If you search around on this stackexchange and also on [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange, you'll find other resources where you can obtain downloadable and online DEM's.
2. Add the elevation values to your point layer. You can use the `Sample Raster Values` processing algorithm (shown below) or the Point Sampling Tool plugin.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed and easy to follow response! With some troubleshooting, I was able to get it to work, although I used the Point Sampling Tool instead of Sample Raster Values.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added your suggestion of using the Point Sampling Tool plugin, which may be helpful to others with the same question.

Answer (score 3):

- You'll need to search for a high resolution elevation raster for your area.
- Open it in QGIS along with your GPS points.
- Make a copy of your GPS points.
- Use the 'Drape' tool in the processing toolbox to add z values to the points using the elevation raster.

Google terrain/satellite is not going to work.  You will have to source a high resolution elevation raster.  If you're in the US, check out [USGS 3dep](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/3dep/about-3dep-products-services) for elevation rasters.  You will need 1m resolution if you want improved accuracy over your GPS device (which are usually around 10m).

Comment: Thanks, so much! This helped me figure it out!